# Multiple home pages for different roles in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working on getting the Spring Boot app up and running with security features. I'm having some difficulties to get it to run for that I have created other questions. This problem however is a bit on a functionality side. I have multiple roles like ADMIN and CUSTOMER and after login I want to send them to their respective online pages. One way I figured out is by creating a single landing page and then redirect them using cookies though I don't know how to do that. Could you please provide with any examples if my approach is right or if there's default functionality provided by Spring Boot, please let me know.

This is my SecurityConfig class:

```
package com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception 
    {
        auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
            authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "CUSTOMER")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()                
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception 
    {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by dur I might need to do something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {


@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
    User authUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); 
    session.setAttribute("username", authUser.getUsername());        

    //set our response to OK status
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    // Now I need to redirect the user based on his role.
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("home");
}
```

}

Now the question is how do I get the name of role from authUser. I hope I'm doing this right and I don't need to do anything else. Secondly how do I fit this successful handler to my SecurityConfig class. Please highlight the change that needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dur suggested I resolved this problem by doing adding a CustomSuccessHandler:

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler 
{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) 
                    throws IOException, ServletException, RuntimeException 
    {
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
        User authUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        session.setAttribute("username", authUser.getUsername());
        //set our response to OK status
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        authorities.forEach(authority -> 
                                { 
                                    if(authority.getAuthority().equals("ADMIN_ROLE")) 
                                    { 
                                        session.setAttribute("role", AppRole.ADMIN);
                                        try
                                        {
                                            //since we have created our custom success handler, its up to us to where
                                            //we will redirect the user after successfully login
                                            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/admin/home");
                                        } 
                                        catch (IOException e) 
                                        {
                                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                        }                                                                           
                                    }
                                    else if (authority.getAuthority().equals("CUSTOMER_ROLE"))
                                    {
                                        session.setAttribute("role", AppRole.CUSTOMER);
                                        try
                                        {
                                            //since we have created our custom success handler, its up to us to where
                                            //we will redirect the user after successfully login
                                            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/user/home");
                                        } 
                                        catch (IOException e) 
                                        {
                                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                        }   
                                    }
                                });

    }
}
```

And I added this by configuring:

```
http.
    authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("CUSTOMER_ROLE")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN_ROLE").anyRequest()               
        .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .successHandler(successHandler) // successHandler is a reference to my CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler
        ....
```

Answer (score -1):

At first try to get **SecurityContext** from **SecurityContextHolder**
(which is the holder for **SecurityContext**) where spring framework keep 
**Authentication** object after successful authentication.Using **SecurityContext** you can get **Authentication** object as 
**securityContext.getAuthentication()** and you can get user role from the 
**Authentication** object and using this **Authentication** object,check 
user role and redirect to different home page for different user role.

Comment: Do we need to do that in SecurityConfig? And how do I do it?

Comment: No you don't need to do that in SecurityConfig....just make one utility class from where you can get user role only.....and check that user role in your controller class.